# How can display a message on terminal when open it

Tags: command-line

how can i display a message when open terminal.

i want to display a Specified text right after open terminal any time.

hence before do anything,i want that text will shown.

i want to understand what file or files should change...

thank you

Comment: Not a duplicate, if you look for adding a message to starting a terminal this is the first hit
you would never find those other questions with a regular google search
+1 for the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add it to your `~/.bashrc`. That file is read each time a new interactive shell is launched so it will be displayed each time you launch a terminal, or log in to the console or simply run `bash`. For example, you could add these lines:

```
echo "Hi, how are 'ya?"
```

Comment: its work but not when  i open a new session terminal. it just work when i login with superuser.

Comment: @smse what exactly did you do?

Comment: after login with superuser, in .bashrc append this line : echo "Hi, how are 'ya?"

Comment: @smse why did you log in as the super user? You should do this as your regular user. Otherwise, you are modifying root's `.bashrc` and not yours.