# Holidayifying My Prompt

Tags: login, customization

With Christmas around the corner, I'd like to make my system's prompt (for every user) a bit more festive and cheery.

Namely, I'd like to attach a `Happy Holidays!` (or similar) message post-login for every user on the system (on terminal login, SSH or locally). I'd assume this is a simple `echo` command, but I'm not sure where the appropriate place to put this command is in such a way that it would affect everyone. For obvious reasons, I'd rather not modify everyone's `.bashrc`. So, where is that?

Comment: Maybe pipe your input to `lolcat`? I know its far from what you want, but a little color doesn't kill. :)

Comment: You can't paste emojis in your terminal? O.o Then open `.bashrc` with gedit or something.

Comment: (the "show message at login" part should be a separate question)

Comment: @muru, done. question de-duplicatified.

Comment: Ok. What sort of login? GUI? TTY? SSH? If GUI, what do you want to do? Open a terminal and run a command?

Comment: Ive seen this in sshd_config. Theres banner, and something else. basicly there are text files, for this. you would insert your greeting

Comment: @j0h, How would that work locally?

Comment: @KazWolfe see http://askubuntu.com/a/100058/158442 `pam_motd` does the MOTD for both SSH and local logins.

Comment: http://www.fontspace.com/category/tree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can display a message on terminal when open it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/591787/how-can-display-a-message-on-terminal-when-open-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux can do this using the `/etc/motd` system, or any system that extends that (namely, `update-motd`).

Given this information, it's possible to add a simple shell script to `/etc/update-motd.d/40-holiday`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Happy holidays from your local sysadmin!
```

Upon marking this as runnable (`sudo chmod a+x /etc/update-motd.d/40-holiday`), the MOTD can be forcefully updated using the command `update-motd` (as root).

Any subsequent logins will use the new (expanded) MOTD, finally bringing some holiday cheer to anybody who has to log on to a server on Christmas day.

Note that this method depends on the `update-motd` package, which *should* be pre-installed. But if it's not, `sudo apt install update-motd`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to inject a christmas tree emoji () into my own PS1 prompt somehow

Try using \u1f384 and reference https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt for common pitfalls.

> I'd also like to attach a "Happy Holidays!" message to every user's shell (at login only).

I would suggest changing the motd banner, if I understand what you want correctly. I don't remember off the top of my head how it's done best in Ubuntu, but if you want to be lazy you could modify one of the files in /etc/update-motd.d/, such as `98-reboot-required` and throw an `echo "Happy Holidays!";` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSH and `motd`, don't forget to update `sshd_config`.

Change:
`PrintMotd no`
to:
`PrintMotd yes`

And restart the ssh server to apply the changes.